# Highcharts legendItemClick event - Stop chart auto rendering

Tags: highcharts

Is there any possibility to stop rendering a chart in high chart on legendItemclick event.

In my current scenario , there are six columns, where the second column is placed in mid of the first column , using series.PointWidth and series.groupPadding options and respectively for other columns.
 when I click on any legend the columns are collapsed and irregular. 
I just want to place the other column in same position and just hide other column for which the legend is toggled.

Comment: In general stopping from 'auto rendering' or just redrawing chart doesn't make sense - if you will do that, then you won't hide series at all. Maybe you have something wrong set in code - recreate issue on jsFiddle and we will look into this.

Comment: Here is a live example : http://jsfiddle.net/T48wW/3/   . For example if the click on the legend actual 2013, the whole alignment if the chart is changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general it should be possible to achieve with `ignoreHiddenSeries: false`, but looks like it's a little buggy: http://jsfiddle.net/6GCbp/. Reported [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2764), thanks!